# Attachments in Apex SOQL Subquery

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I have custom objects Team member and Employment, and there's a lookup relationship from employment(many) to team member(one), plus another lookup record on team member called `current employment`.

The employment record may have attachments.

I want a SOQL query, to run in an APEX class, which will return attachments information for specific team members.

So far I have this:

```
SObject[] results = [select id,(select id,name from Attachments) from Employment__c where id in (select Current_Employment__c from Team_Member__c where id=:id)];
```

Wnen I run the query in the schema browser, it works OK and I'm able to drill-down to the attachments, but when I run it in Apex (Anonymous), the result set does not contain the attachments:

```
for (SObject result : results) {
  System.debug(result);
}
```

I can only see the Employment id in the results.

How can I get attachments in APEX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do following to get list of attachment related to that object.

```
Employment__c[] results = [select id,(select id,name from Attachments)  from Employment__c where id in (select Current_Employment__c from Team_Member__c where id=:id)];    

for (Employment__c result : results) {
   if(result.Attachments!=null){
       List<Attachment> AttachmentList=result.Attachments;
   }
}
```